# I'm getting a corrupted value from Spring Redis MessageReceiver

Tags: java, spring, redis, jedis

I'm playing with Spring/Redis/Jedis for a simple message queue system. I've brought up a simple test case using just Strings, but for some reason the strings are coming back corrupted. I was originally trying with POJOs, but that also had corruption, so I figured just simple strings would work, but so far no luck.

When I use redis-cli and subscribe to the channel the raw data it shows me is

```
1) "message"
2) "test"
3) "\xac\xed\x00\x05t\x00\x03wee"
```

Here is my sample code

```
@Service
public class MessageService {
    @Autowired private RedisTemplate<String, String> testTemplate;

    @Bean
    RedisMessageListenerContainer container(JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory,
                                            MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {

        RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory);
        container.addMessageListener(listenerAdapter, new PatternTopic("test"));

        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter() {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(this, "receiveMessage");
    }

    public void sendMessage(){
        TestObject message = new TestObject();
        message.test = 5;
        testTemplate.convertAndSend("test", "wee");
    }

    public void receiveMessage(String testObject) {
        System.out.println("I got a message " + testObject);
    }
}
```

The output from receieveMessage is `I got a message ?? t wee`, well there are two characters that can't be displayed in stackoverflow where the spaces are before and after the 't'.

Any ideas as to what is causing this corruption?

Comment: Spring Data Redis uses `JdkSerializationRedisSerializer` for serializing values. Use `StringRedisSerializer` or `RedisStringTemplate` if you want to use strings. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/redis/core/RedisTemplate.html and http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#redis:serializer

Comment: I'm already using the RedisTemplate<String,String>, and even if I put in `testTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        testTemplate.setDefaultSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());` I still get the same corruption. And from looking at the RedisMessageListenerContainer it appears to use the default StringRedisSerializer.

Comment: There is also a `setValueSerializer()`, but `setDefaultSerializer()` should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String,String> redisTemplate() {
        final RedisTemplate<String,String> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String,String>();
        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new GenericToStringSerializer<>(Object.class));
        redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        return redisTemplate;
    }
```

Your RedisTemplate value serializer should be StringRedisSerializer. Use this conf  for RedisTemplate.